# How to design Expandable List View with checkbox and image as child in android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am required to design a layout in android where I have:

1. 1 Child List Item (with Image as Child)
2. 3 Childless List Items

Here is the image attached similar to what I require:

[image]

Here is my code:

***main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:id="@+id/mainListView">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

***simplerow.xml***

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/rowTextView" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

***MainMenuActivity.java***

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity {

      private ListView mainListView ;
      private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;


      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );


        String[] menuItems = new String[] { "Safety assistance", "Edit emergency message", "Send emeregency pictures", "Message Interval",
                                          "Emeregency contacts"};  
        ArrayList<String> menuList = new ArrayList<String>();
        menuList.addAll( Arrays.asList(menuItems) );


        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, menuItems);




        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );      
}
```

Comment: see the custom list view examples.

Comment: hav u try out some code to work with this

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper Yes I did! I am having difficult to include a child list item. The image under Safety Assistance (What you see in the attached screenshot) is the child item that I want to include.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the links you might like to use it.

- http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html
- http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-create-custom-expandablelistview.html
- http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/25/android-practice-custom-expandablelistview-sample-2/
- http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html
- http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/11/expandable-listview-with-custom-parent.html